# Return NSOutlineView's numberOfChildrenOfItem after a web request

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have a list of around 1500 items in my outline view, the children of each item is determined by an API call as the API only gives me all the parents without the children.

Because it is 1500 items I am unable to make a request for each parent to list their children at application startup, therefore I would prefer to return `numberOfChildrenOfItem`, as it is called after a user expands an item, for an item after a web request has completed

Example code of how my API works:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {

    // code to determine if root or parent

    } else if parent {
        api.updateDatabaseChildren(for: parent) {
            // database has been updated and parent now has children
        }
    }

}
```

I am truly unable to work this one out, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Start with having your data source return `1` for each parent's `numberOfChildrenOfItem`, and `true` for `isExpandable`.

For the child item in each parent that has not yet loaded its children, supply a dummy item that displays something like "Loading…":

```
> Parent
> Parent
v Parent
     Loading...
> Parent
```

When the user expands a parent item, load its children asynchronously from the API. When you have received the results, use `insertItems()` to insert the child items into their parent item.

Comment: My `ofItem` returns the position at the index of an array within a parent and as `ofItem` is never called on the parent again the list is always out of date. Does this mean I should not use the item initially given and instead read directly from my database?

Comment: What do you mean by "read directly from my database"? You don't want to / can't do those asynchronous API calls in your data source, which expects an immediate answer. If you can get the child counts for all parents right away, simply return the actual counts. For the items, trigger an API call when the parent is expanded, display placeholder content, and reload the item when your API call returns, displaying the correct data.